# PHP Syntax Error in Setting Global Variable

Tags: php, syntax, global-variables

Ok, so my PHP is, to say the least, horrible.  I inherited an application and am having to fix errors in it from someone that wrote it over 7 years ago.  When I run the page, there is no return, so I checked the logs to see the error and here is what i get:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';' in /httpdocs/cron123/purge.php on line 4

Here is the code:

```
<?
ob_start();

global $siteRoot    =   '/httpdocs/';
global $reportRoot  =   '/reports/';
include('billing1.php');    

$date='Purge report for: ' .date('M d, Y \a\t g:i a'); ?>

<html>
<head><title><?=$date?></title></head>
<body>

<?php       
    $account = new billing();
    $ftresult = $account->purge();
    new dBug($ftresult);        
    echo "successfully wrote";
?>
</body>
<? 
    $filename = "purge_report_" . date('y.m.d_\a\t_g_i_a') . ".html";
    $loc = $reportRoot . 'purge_reports/';
    $f = $loc . $filename;

    $fp = @fopen($f, 'w'); 
    @fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents());
    @fclose($fp);

    ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`global`](http://nl2.php.net/global) is a keyword that should be used by itself. It must not be combined with an assignment. So, chop it:

```
global $x;
$x = 42;
```

Also, as [Zenham](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145970/php-syntax-error-in-setting-global-variable/1145985#1145985) mentions, `global` is used inside functions, to access variables in an outer scope. So the use of `global` as it is presented makes little sense.

Another tip (though it will not really help you with syntax errors): add the following line to the top of the main file, to help debugging ([documentation](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting)):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 4):

The **global** keyword is used inside of functions to declare that they will use a globally defined variable, not to define one. Just remove the word **global**, and if you need those values in functions, add:

```
global $a;
```

...to the start to the function.

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). `global` is a modifier which means the variable comes from the global scope. It should just be

```
<?
ob_start();

$siteRoot        =       '/httpdocs/';
$reportRoot      =       '/reports/';
```

and in functions which use them (but you don't have any in this page)

```
function f() {
  global $siteRoot, $reportRoot;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use global without assignment, only a variable.

As you do not functions, there is no need for the global keyword at all:

```
$siteRoot        =       '/httpdocs/';
$reportRoot      =       '/reports/';
```

If you need the variables in a function just add:

```
global $siteRoot;
global $reportRoot
```