# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';' when using PDO connection script

Tags: php, mysql

I have copied the PDO connection script directly from the php.net documentation, however, it fails to work, because it gets this error.

```
<?php
  global $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pionear', "root", "");
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Please cite the link so the docs can be reviewed.

Comment: `PDO('dblib:host=your_hostname;dbname=your_db;charset=UTF-8', $user, $pass);`

Comment: Doubtful this is actually a copy/paste from the PHP documentation, since a Google search can't find your code.  https://www.google.com/search?num=20&safe=active&q="global+%24pdo+%3D+new+PDO"&oq="global+%24pdo+%3D+new+PDO"

Comment: Just cited the docs, despite changing some of the variables to string literals, it is more or less the same.

Comment: Oh, great, now you edit your question to remove the syntax error?  Fantastic...

Comment: It's not a doc problem; you replaced $user and $pass with your own data and caused a parse error.

Comment: I typed it in incorrectly, and that was not the issue.

Comment: @Brad the error would have been different if that was the actual mistake.

Comment: @TomUdding We don't know what was on other lines.  Either the mistake was caused by the broken quotes, or the mistake is elsewhere.  Either way, this question is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Syntax Error in Setting Global Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1145970/5914775)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare a variable in the global scope like that. You have to declare it as a normal variable and than access it through `global` (e.g. in a function):

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pionear', "root", "");

function something() {
    global $pdo;
    $pdo->doSometing();
}

something();
```

You can check the documentation on the [`global`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword for more information. If you do not want to use the `global` keyword you can instead use [`$GLOBALS`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) (which is a 'superglobal', thus no need to do `global $pdo;`).

Comment: Good catch.  I'm surprised this threw a syntax error, but it makes sense.

Comment: @Brad but a different one than the title, which only goes to show it was an edit to correct the obviousness of not a doc problem.  It would have caused ```Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or `';'' in Command line code on line 1```

Comment: @Spechal It's definitely not a documentation problem as Jack's code was not copied/pasted from the docs as he asserted.

Comment: @Brad I saw the edit, he replaced $user and $pass with "root, "" and forgot a quote.

Comment: @Spechal He also added `global`.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's not a good idea to use global variables in the first place - they should be passed as arguments to the function, that way you have more control over which variables are in what scope.